# D365 Ribbon Workbench subgrid button not visible

Tags: button, dynamics-crm, crm, subgrid, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have a D365 form with two subgrids. I have to add a button on one of the subgrid.

I'm trying to achieve this using ribbon workbench, but facing issues.

Issue 1: How to specify the subgrid on which i want to show my button?

Issue 2: Right now, button is not visible on either of the two subgrid.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention "**D365**", I assume your **Dynamics** version is greater than **v9.0**. Below suggestion for issue 2 only works for **v9.0 or later**.

For issue 1: You can add an enable rule for your ribbon, and write some JS function for this enable rule. You can pass `primaryControId` as a parameter this should be the subgrid name and then use it in your code to determine show/hide your ribbon.

For issue 2: You can use the `ribbondebug` function to debug your ribbon, you can enable it by adding `&ribbondebug=true` at the end of the URL. After you refresh your page, at the end of the ribbon area will occur a ribbon called "Command checker", click the "Command checker" and switch to "Command properties" tab, finally you can see all the rules and function results bound to the ribbon, check all the listed result. You can see more info from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-apps/ribbon-issues-button-hidden?tabs=delete)